How to implement CP tensor completion with extra calculations?
I am new to tensor decomposition. I want to know from a practical point of view, how to use an already known tool/library to compute CP factorization for tensor completion. Specifically, I want to implement what is proposed in this paper (you can see the formula on page 14 and the explanation of the dimensions on page 13). There are two extra calculations involved in the formula, you can see it in the image below (DB and TC are tensor-matrix products as far as i understand). What tool could i use?

For instance, i found this library which allow to specify a loss function, and there is an example of tensor completion but there is little documentation on how to add this extra calculations inside the loss function.
